# Checking format of String and casting it to object

Tags: java

Is there exists some elegant and convinient way to check if string is of following format (example)?

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm:ss; 3.3"
```

I mean following format:

```
"timestamp  ;  double "
```

The aim is cast this string to object:

```
class A {
   Timestamp t;
   double d;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could write a regular expression for this particular case. If you're asking "Can I tell if my string is a concatenation of the string versions of two arbitrary classes?" then no, you can't.

Comment: Why don't you split and try to parse?

Comment: I am searching for black-box (maybe regex) solution

Comment: Can you suggest some regex ?

Comment: Maybe you can split the String then have different constructors accepting different types. Sort of MyClass(String), MyClass(TimeStamp). Regardless of what you parse you can create s new class, or have the class accept a multitude of setters with different types. The drawback is that you do not exactly get a Class A like you want it.